# Asus ROG Zephyrus S GX502GW headphone jack not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, asus, audio-jack

i am in trouble and would appreciate some help. I cant manage to get my headphone jack to work on either Ubuntu desktop 18.04, 19.04, or 20.04; also tried pop os 19.Right now using Ubuntu desktop 19.10. I have followed the following link (https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/) until the end, but still no luck. Here is the alsa info.

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=d04c62472e1ce16822f339c255cf6b2dd6881681

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i have specified the requested info.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i made the changes alredy. however, the alsa info link specifies clearly all the details.

Comment: can yo actually help?

Comment: yes ,sound does work through the speakers. I have tried other headphones.

Comment: Please take a bore inspection light or similar very small LED light and physically examine the interior of the jack for a foreign object.

Comment: i did already, still not working. And it does work in Windows

Comment: BTW, what is the make and model part number (from the serial number sticker) of your machine? I ask you to search for that part number because model names elsewhere on the machine are generally marketing names and not useful in finding the HW manual and other useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the RealTek ACL294 sound device is not fully supported in ALSA on the Asus GX502GW. This is because it's a new configuration so it hasn't been patched into ALSA yet.

This is impacting Arch and Debian distros, and the newest kernel that I have tested (5.4.0-37) is the same.

Output of `dmesg | grep snd

```
[    4.075183] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.075257] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    4.075262] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    4.094050] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC294: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    4.094053] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.094054] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    4.094055] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    4.094056] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    4.094057] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x12
[   19.896933] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC2D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 38
[   20.920927] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC2D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 8
```

It seems that a correctly configured system will show `hp_outs=1`.

Other instances with the same model laptop:

- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=306891
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249456
- [Headphone jack doesn't work in Asus GX502GW](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213943/headphone-jack-doesnt-work-in-asus-gx502gw)
- [Ubuntu not detecting Headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216134/ubuntu-not-detecting-headphones)

It may be worth making a ticket on ALSA to support this OOTB.

Comment: Update: There is a Bug in ALSA's pipeline for this model of system: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208005